# After changing project name, cannot find version setting

Tags: ios, xcode, build, version

Using XCode 4 for iOS.  I changed the project name of my program to something more user friendly and readable.  I can no longer find the version setting.
Is there another setting I need to change to view and edit version/build?
Thanks...Rick

Answer (score 2):

I have tried in XCode and rename the project.
The Xcode will automatically ask you to rename the target etc.
Afterward, I could still find the version and build in Target summary and info.

I rename the project name in the following way :
1. Select Project (the top row with blue icon)
2. Press Enter
3. Rename
4. And continue with xCode suggestion for renaming other related files

I hope this help